# W10 disable welcome screen, but keep lock screen?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, lock-screen, wake-up

Is this possible via a regedit or something?

To reiterate: the welcome screen is the one where you select a user account and type in your password (if you've set one), and the lock screen is the one with those Spotlight tooltips which you swipe up to get the welcome screen.

I know of Netpwliz, as well as in the Settings app disabling the lock- and welcome screen when going to sleep, but that's not what I'm asking.

I basically want to have it so that you only have to swipe up or any other form of input to unlock a woken device to immediately show the desktop.

Comment: So, you don't want to have to enter a password or perform another form of security authentication in order to unlock a device?

Comment: What edition of Windows 10 are you using? You should be able to disable the Welcome Screen with a group policy.